# How to scroll horizontally inside overflowed div

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a div with multiple inline divs inside, they are displayed as a row/column arrangement. I would like to make the div a fixed width, however the entries within it might extend beyond its width so I would like to implement a slider to be able to scroll the div horizontally. What are the properties that need to be called on the div in order to scroll it horizontally as the slider changes? I am implementing this as an angular directive (I only want to know the properties needed to make the div scroll horizontally.)

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alanz2223/5jbju3rb/)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="entries">

    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>

  </div>

  <input type="range" />

</div>

#container
{
  width:500px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.entries
{
  padding:10px;
}


.entry
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:130px;
  height:130px;
  background:chartreuse;
}
```

Comment: Um... are you asking to have a scroll-bar at the bottom of the div so that you can scroll through the overflowed content? If so, just use CSS. Apply the style `overflow-x:auto;` to your parent div. If you still see the content flowing out of the containing div, wrap your div in another containing div and apply the style `overflow:hidden;` to it.

Comment: element.scrollLeft is settable in vanilla JS.  (I'd recommend using a real overflow scrollbar instead of rolling your own slider, though.)

Comment: no I do not find the scroll bar aesthetically pleasing, I would like a custom slider, and the slider would act like a scroll bar.

Comment: OK.  Be aware of the accessibility issues you'll be creating, at least.

Comment: I have added a fiddle and accompanying code. @DanielBeck what could happen?

Comment: Lots could happen:  The user doesn't realize what your slider is for, because they're used to scrolling with native scrollbars.  Or they scroll your block manually (on a touchscreen, say, or using mouse wheel) and your slider doesn't update to match. Or a screenreader doesn't recognize the relation between the scrollable area and the slider because there isn't a standard ARIA role for this (or because you didn't know to include one).  I'm not saying it can't be done, just that you'll have to put in a lot of work to reproduce native functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... this is what you want...

```
<div class="width:400px;height:200px;overflow:auto">
   <div class="display:inline">Some Inline Div</div>
   <div class="display:inline">Some Inline Div</div>
   <div class="display:inline">Some Inline Div</div>
</div>
```

But if the built in scrollbar doesn't work for you visually, then your best bet is to use a jQuery plugin to augment the slider.

Comment: I have something going on, the problem is that the width's of the containers keep on changing as I adjust the margin's but take a look. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alanz2223/5jbju3rb/1/)

Comment: do you know how to obtain the initial width of the element?

Comment: It was a mistake on my part, I was using the wrong value.